# AJAX with image button

Tags: java, ajax

I have tried different combinations of input type but how am I able to input a message without messing up the image? The purpose was to update the table without refreshing the page. To be more specific, when I clicked the image it should update the table on the side of the page. For many of the tutorial out there I saw people only use  for onclick to call the ajax functions. Is there a good example for what I can do for the image button instead of the plain button?

For example:

```
<form name="bakery" action="TestMartController" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="dairy">
    <input type="image" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/categories/dairy.jpg" onclick="loadXMLDoc">
```

The table I want to update is

```
<div id="refresh">  
    <table class="rightTable" border="1" width="70%">
    <tr>
        <th>Photo</th>
        <th>Product and Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Orders</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Edit Quantity</th>
        <th>Add Item </th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="b" items="${bakery}">
...
    </c:forEach>    
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript file

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 ) {
       if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
           document.getElementById("refresh").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
       else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
          alert('There was an error 400');
       }
       else {
           alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
       }
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("POST", "bakery.jsp", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: For new JS programmers wanting to do AJAX calls, I would recommend using a JS library (such as JQuery) to speed up the learning curve.  There are many gotchas, issues, workarounds that have been fixed already by these libraries and you don't have to worry about one of them interfering with your progress.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you want a ajax call which makes post to a service and get datas and update your table.

I suggest to you learn how to use jquery and ajax call.

1- In your html define call method. Don't use form!

```
<img src="yourImage.jpg" onclick="getSomeData()">
```

2- Make post or get call to your service with jquery. And get Data.

```
function getSomeData(){
var url = "http://url";
    $.post(url,{data:data})
    .done(function(data){
       //this data is your call result.
       //do something
       updateTable(data);
    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log('fail');
    });

}
```

3- Create your gui function to change table.

```
function updateTable(){
//update your htmls
}
```

Comment: the page still refresh when submitted

Comment: I changed my answer. You have to learn ajax call, create service, change html.

Comment: If I dont use form how do I pass action to the servlet.java?

Comment: $.post will send your action.